# Need a link to the rules

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, moderation, vote-to-close

I'm not sure if this where it's brought up, but i can't see any other avenue to discuss (or  query) why this question was closed.

Should this be the wrong avenue, please email on my username with a dot between the first and second names at gmail.

**CRUX:**

There are plenty of questions in the career, work-environment and lifestyle tags where you could replace 'programmer' (or your favorite synonym) slice of text with near all professions or lifestyle choices.

Considering [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/what-can-i-keep-my-hand-occupied-with) was both asked by a programmer (with application to activity whilst programming), and received responses from (i assume) other programmers (due to the perceived audience), why was it closed?  Was it not relevant to programmers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you, perchance, take a look at the FAQ? It's linked all over the place, including

- the top of the page
- the bottom of the page
- on the mandatory greeting for new users (two places)
- on the /questions/ask page seen when asking a new question

Short of driving to your home and delivering you a hand-embossed, countersigned, wax sealed copy ... I'm not sure what else to do other than provide the very same link:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Read closely, particularly the top 4 or 5 paragraphs and related bulleted lists.

Comment: I appreciate the exhaustively complete description of how i missed that.

Comment: Also, the hand-embossed edition would be a most welcome addition to my library, would you like beer or wine when you bring it over?

Comment: @stafford a /faq reading party is always good times!